# Proof that the sum $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} (-1)^n \sin (nx)$ is bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

How can I prove that there is some constant $M>0$, such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in [0,\pi]$,
$$\left|\sum _{n=1} ^{N} (-1)^n \sin (nx)\right| < M\text{?}$$

Comment: I assume you mean $\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\sin(nx)<M$ for all $x\in[0,\pi]$, $N\in\mathbb N$? Note that the full series need not converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly
$$
(-1)^n \sin nx = \mathrm{Im}\, \mathrm{e}^{nxi+n\pi i},
$$
and thus, for $k\ne m\pi$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k \sin kx = \mathrm{Im}\, \sum_{k=1}^n\mathrm{e}^{k(x+\pi) i}=
\mathrm{Im}\,\frac{\mathrm{e}^{(n+1)(x+\pi) i}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{(x+\pi) i}-1},
$$
and hence
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k \sin kx\,\right| \le 
\left|\frac{\mathrm{e}^{(n+1)(x+\pi) i}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{(x+\pi) i}-1}\,\right|\le \frac{2}{2|\cos (x/2)|},
$$
since
$$
\mathrm{e}^{(x+\pi) i}-1=\mathrm{e}^{(x+\pi) i/2}\left(\mathrm{e}^{(x+\pi) i/2}-\mathrm{e}^{-(x+\pi) i/2}\right)=2i\sin((x+\pi)/2)\mathrm{e}^{(x+\pi) i/2}-2i\cos(x/2)\mathrm{e}^{(x+\pi)}.
$$
Also, if $x=m\pi$, then this sum vanishes.

Note. The sum is bounded for every $x$, but it is not uniformly bounded.

Comment: It is not clear from the problem statement, but this shows that the bound is not uniform in $x$ ($\cos\frac x2$ can be arbitrarily small if $x\approx \pi$)

Comment: Hagen is right, I want to show that there's some constant M, wich does not depend on x, that satisfies the statement.